# How to make 'Search in page' find words split across multiple elements?

Tags: html, css

I want to display some text, split into groups of a given length, but **retain the ability to search  the page for text that spans multiple groups**. With this, I want to display some character above each group.

The solution I've ended up with is the following one:

```css
  body {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    font-family: mono;
  }

  br {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }

  span {
    margin-right: 1rem;
    position: relative;
  }

  .absolute-before::before {
    content: "⇣";
    position: absolute;
    top: -1.2rem;
    left: 0;
    color: red;
  }

  .static-before::before {
    content: "⇣";
    color: green;
  }
```

```html
   <span class="absolute-before">This_is_a_sp</span><span class="absolute-before">lit_string</span>

   <br />

   <span class="static-before">This_is_a_sp</span><span class="static-before">lit_string</span>
```

*Note: the string and split position are hard-coded here, but are dynamically calculated in the real case.*

The first one (red arrows) makes the visual part of the job is perfectly fine, but the problem is that, *in Firefox* (tested in Chromium, where it works), searching the page for the text `split`, which is split between the two groups, gives no results.
The second one (green arrows), conversely, does not give a good visual but the search feature works well.
The difference is in the `position: absolute` on the `::before` in the first one, which seems to break the search feature.

Do you have any clue on how to achieve that ? I am not fixed on the way of achieving this (especially the `::before` way), so any idea is welcome ! The only requirement is to use the browser's native *Search in page...* tool.

**Edit:**

I've found a [Bugzilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1774250) also reporting this problem. So it seems unlikely to solve it using the `::before` method  . Any other solution still welcome !

Comment: use `document.body.textContent`

Comment: you said that you tested it in Chromium and it worked and I wonder how. Since the search feature should perform its job on the rendered text and the word `split` (in this example), since splitted, won't be found whatever browser you are using. I think you need to perform a js search feature of your own operating on the full text that you may have saved somehow (hidden) before performing the splitting. Did I get it right? Do my words make sense?

Comment: if you are performing your splitting via js starting from the full text, you may store the text belonging to each given `<span>` inside a data attribute. In this example the word `split` should belong to both the span. And when you perform your js search function, it should iterate over all the spans, look for the searched word in that data attribute, and when found, add a css class to those span that will highlight those elements

Comment: @DiegoD I don't know either how it works but if you open this page in Chromium, run the snippet and search for `split` (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>), you'll see that it works. I think that this is because it is a unique string in the markup (because the `<span>` are side-by-side with no space between them), and thus it is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I cannot use it for 2 reasons : 1) I need to use the native browser search, and 2) I may want to search for text that is not exact words (actually, its not words in my real case but a sequence of unrelated characters ^^') : in this example and with the JS-split solution, searching for *a_split_string* would not get me any result either.

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen I am not sure to understand, do you mean to perform a JS search on `document.body.textContent` ? If yes, I don't want to do a custom search, I want to be able to find the text with native browser search

Comment: @Neluji yes you are right.. indeed searching for the word `split` will highlight also the word splitted in two different spans.. I suppose because those are adjacent elements and their content joins. It really surprised me to see it working like that. And it surprises also Firefox since there it's not working like that. Unfortunately if you are relying on regular browser search, and a given browser does not behave like that, I think you are out of chance with that browser. I can't say for sure there's no way to enable firefox to match that behaviour but I'm skeptical

Comment: @Neluji in the end I came up with something. I hope I didn't discourage you with my words before

Comment: @Neluji I think you didn't get it correctly. You are not supposed to move answers in your own question.. if you are not changing their content in a meaningful way. You also didn't address correctly the problem since the snippet is not working... the arrows don't show up except one. I invite you to read my latest answer that in my opinion correctly addresses the problem still using the spans and dynamically appending arrows without breaking the search target. `LT_` was precious to find that solution (credits to him). And I also invite you to upvote/accept answers that gave a meaningful support

Comment: Yes that is what I noticed and am going to tell but no as fast as you ^^' And I am pretty new to SO (for questioning) so sorry for the bad usage, I will follow your tips

Comment: Just a question: am I supposed to upvote answers which do not address exaclty the problem ?

Comment: you should upvote all the answers and comments that you find enriched you somehow or that gave a valid support to your doubts. And you should accept the answer that according to you correctly answer to your question if it was correctly fulfilled and there's no more space for further development

Comment: I found out that I am too new to SO to upvote actually... 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My former answer was joining the text contents in a single group to enable the native search anywhere.

But the recent answer given by another user (@LS_) inspired me on a different approach. You can still keep using different spans grouping the contents and yet having a working search for the joined text.

The trick here is creating those arrows as new divs being positioned absolute relative to the whole container. Such strategy won't insert text content between groups and will preserve the search like the text was continuous.

**Recap:**

This code includes an HTML having a `<div class="container">` wrapping `<span class="fragment">` items. The Javascript will take care of, at page load, creating an arrow on top of each of those `span.fragment`. The text will be a good search target like if those fragment belonged to a continuous text. **Attention!!** adjacent fragments will be considered a single word no divided by space ONLY as long those spans are on the same line with no newline!

```js
//on page ready
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{  
  //this is the container target
  //NOTE! I'm using querySelector on a classname.. it will return only the first element having that class
  const containerDiv = document.querySelector('.container');
  
  //it draws the arrows inside the target on top of each children span
  redrawArrows(containerDiv);
  
  //sets up an observer that will redraw the arrows when the target container is resized
  const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver( ()=>{
   //using a delay of 50ms before redrawing (to be 100% sure it won't mess up with coords too early)
   setTimeout(() => {
        redrawArrows(containerDiv);
    }, 50);    
  } );
  resizeObserver.observe(containerDiv);
})

function redrawArrows(container){  

  //remove any existing arrows
  container.querySelectorAll('.arrow')
    .forEach(arrow => arrow.remove());

  //for each .fragment in container, adds an arrow in top
  container.querySelectorAll('.fragment')
    .forEach(fragment => addArrowOnTopOfSpan(container, fragment));
}

function addArrowOnTopOfSpan(container, span){  
  document.body.offsetHeight; // Force reflow
  
  //creates a new div to render the arrow
  const arrow = document.createElement('div');
  arrow.classList.add('arrow');    
  arrow.innerHTML = '⇣';    
  arrow.style.left = `${span.offsetLeft}px`;
  //the y coord is shifted 1em upward
  arrow.style.top = `calc( ${span.offsetTop}px - 1em )`;    
  
  container.appendChild(arrow);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.container{
  position: relative;
}

.fragment{
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  /*this is important for the offset coords to work as expected!*/
  display: inline-block;
}

.arrow{
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
}

.note{
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="fragment">This_is_a_very_long_text_to</span><span class="fragment">highlight_a_scenario_where</span><span class="fragment">the_content_will_word_wrap</span><span class="fragment">no_matter_what_even_if_theres</span><span class="fragment">no_space_in_between_words</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again, I've thus came up with a similar solution in my question (that I will remove), but what the one in the question highlights is that, because the positioning is now relative to `<span>`'s bounding box, when they wrap the left of the bounding box is moved to the very left of the paragraph, so the arrow is horizontally positioned relatively to there.

Comment: I brought the whole logic here from the 1st answer including the logic to deal with resizing. I also added `display: inline-block` to the `span.fragment` to make them return a working `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` relative to the container needed for the positioning of the newly created arrows. I think I can't go any further than this

Comment: Thanks again for the efforts ! I know that the `display: inline-block` breaks Chromium search this time (yes it's a real mess ) but as long as we have a solution for both we can chose which approach to use depending on the browser, so I will accept this one ^^

Comment: omg you are right, now it's not working in Chrome. I was focused on Firefox when I did that demo. Today I had some time and spent it on your question. Unfortunately I can't say when I'll have time again to dedicate to SO. And I'm sorry the answer wasn't perfectly correct in all the scenarios. I really did my best

Comment: No worries ahah, looks like this will remain the best answer till Firefox decides to fix this bug - if they ever do (it received a severity update 5 months ago, maybe one day ?)

Answer (score 2):

If the browser's native search feature is a strict requirement, and since Firefox doesn't behave like Chromium does when searching content spanning among adjacent elements, an alternative solution might be to just have the whole content joined upfront, and via JS, just add an arrow at given letter positions. That way the search will be performed correctly and yet you'll have the arrows.

> Note: the string and split position are hard-coded here, but are
> dynamically calculated in the real case.

It's not clear if you can rely on letter positions for those arrows but so far that's the best I could come up with.

The trick was finding the coords belonging to a given letter position and use them to position a newly created element, holding the arrow, on top of the `.content` div.

I used a `monospaced` font that better fits this strategy.

In this demo I also addressed a scenario in which the content will overflow the container so the word wrap will kick in. The question let me understand that your content is a stream of adjacent letters not necessarily belonging to real words and not necessarily having spaces.

So I enforced `word-wrap: break-word;` to break words if not containing spaces.

Since the arrows position rely on how the text was rendered at the time of their creation, every time the container size changes (because of window resizing), there's an observer redrawing the arrows when the event occurs. You'll see when resizing the window, the arrows stick to the same letter they were since the beginning.

**A side effect here is not having any space between fragments like you showed in your example. If that's an important feature to have, I'm afraid this solution is not viable.**

```js
//on page ready
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{  
  //the content target
  const contentDiv = document.querySelector('.content');
  //draws the arrows inside the target
  redrawArrows(contentDiv);
  
  //sets up an observer that will redraw the arrows when the target container is resized
  const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(()=>{redrawArrows(contentDiv);});
  resizeObserver.observe(contentDiv);
})

//inside element, add an arrow on top of given letter position
function addArrowAbovePosition(element, position) {
    //get the specified letter's position in the div
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(element.firstChild, position);
    range.setEnd(element.firstChild, position + 1);
    const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();

    //create the arrow element
    const arrow = document.createElement('div');
    arrow.classList.add('arrow');    
    arrow.innerHTML = '⇣';    
    arrow.style.left = rect.left + 'px';
    arrow.style.top = (rect.top - rect.height) + 'px';    
    
    //append the arrow to the div
    element.appendChild(arrow);
}

//redraw the arrows in element
function redrawArrows(element){
  //remove any existing arrows
  element.querySelectorAll('.arrow')
    .forEach(arrow => arrow.remove());

  //add arrows at custom positions (2, 10, 87)
  addArrowAbovePosition(element, 2); 
  addArrowAbovePosition(element, 10); 
  addArrowAbovePosition(element, 87);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  /*monospaced font will work better in this scenario*/
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.arrow{
  position: absolute;
  color: red;    
}

.content{
  /*word wraps also content not having spaces*/
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /*allows arrows to have their own space among text lines*/
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
This_is_a_very_long_text_to_highlight_a_scenario_where_the_content_will_word_wrap_no_matter_what_even_if_theres_no_space_in_between_words
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the work in this solution ! This approach sounds really interesting as it leaves the string intact so the search feature can still work, and the arrows are external elements which does not interfere. The side effect you mentioned with the spaces is actually an issue, but I think it can be avoided by mixing this solution with the one I gave, that is using `<span>` to divide the text without separating it in different blocks. I will give a try in an edit of my question.

Comment: I took the time to add a new answer inspired by @LS_. He found out why the search was not working in firefox and once I knew why it was easy to circumvent the issue. In the other answer I still kept the separate spans but instead of using ::before or ::after I positioned the arrows as new element using `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` coming from those spans relative to the container. That way you won't have new content breaking your search target

Answer (score 1):

It seems the Firefox issue is caused by the pseudo element, because it places itself between the 2 words. If you use `:before` on the first `span` and `:after` on the second `span` search works on Firefox too.

Updated example:

```css
body {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

span.after::after,
span.before::before {
  content: "⇣";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.2rem;
  left: 0;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="before">This_is_a_sp</span><span class="after">lit_string</span>
```

The issue with this solution is that you're limited to 2 spans, you can't do something like:

```
<span class="before">This_is_a_sp</span><span class="after">lit_stri</span><span class="before">ng</span>
```

Because the pseudo element again places itself between the 2 words. To make it more clear:

[image: Pseudo element issue example]

Comment: you got the reason! yes it makes perfectly sense. I didn't get that far because I was dismissing the whole attempt considering it not appropriate. And at the same time you hinted another solution! to solve a spans count > 2 the arrow could have no text content and use a background picture instead. Or some other positioning strategy. Anyway it shows my solution went too far.

Comment: Indeed, this is the presence of the pseudo-elements between the `<span>`'s contents which break the search feature, but what is really obscure is the fact that it only **breaks when those pseudo-elements are absolutely positioned**. That is, when position is not set, they won't interfere in the search, even if they are displayed in the middle of the text. I edited the question so you can see an example.

Comment: @DiegoD I was thinking about the background picture solution too, but it still requires to specify a `content: '';` which still breaks the solution for more than 2 spans. I'll try and update the answer later if I find anything relevant. Btw I think your's an appropriate solution, I just wanted to check if it was solvable without using js